# How would I use StreamWriter/Reader to only update text file and program text box when high score is reached

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a game program with a text file that preloads into the program with a high score. I need the program to update the textbox in the program only when a high score is reached.

Currently the return value for the high score text box is each entry or game session (Dice Rolled).

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        string highScore;

        StreamReader inputFile;

        inputFile = File.OpenText("Highscore.txt");

        HighscoreBox.Items.Clear();

        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            highScore = inputFile.ReadLine();

            HighscoreBox.Items.Add(highScore);

        }

        inputFile.Close();



    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: FYI [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) to avoid the StreamReader.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't really use the Writer to control that.  You would setup a method for WriteScores( );  Then you would have end-game logic that says

```
 foreach( object item in HighScoreBox.Items)
 {
    cast item to what you need, see if it is higher than that current score type
    if yes -- call WriteScores(); and end your foreach loop.
 }
```

No actual code was harmed in writing this answer.

Comment: Even if I need the game to displays the previous high score on the form. And the value is suppose to be loaded from a text file that the game creates whenever a winner beats this score?